# Magento : add script to all footer's pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

i have a script for showing modal box by footer link :

```
<script>

...

</script>
```

How can i put that script in the footer of all magento pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add script in footer using `footer.phtml` located in

```
[app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\page\html\footer.phtml]
```

Comment: Can you pls explain how can we add JS in footer using page.xml ?

Comment: It only adds in head section and the question is to add script to all footer's pages !!

Comment: sorry it's my mistake pls see my updated answer and thanks for pointing me out

Answer (score 1):

Just go to system config->design->footer and type your script in misc. html box. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through two options:

1. You can edit template\page\html\footer.phtml file and put your script.
2. You can create new js file for the same and load it into header through layout\page.xml file.

Hope this solution will for for you.